# D365 - Get solution list which contains specific string in 'uniquename'

Tags: dynamics-crm, microsoft-dynamics, query-expressions

I want to get list of list of solution displayed in DropDown in windows application.

So, to get the list of solutions I have written below `QueryExpression` and added a filter for the same:

```
    public EntityCollection GetSolutions(IOrganizationService service, string solutionUniqueNameLike)
    {
        QueryExpression querySampleSolution = new QueryExpression
        {
            EntityName = "solution",
            ColumnSet = new ColumnSet(new string[] { "publisherid", "installedon", "version", "versionnumber", "friendlyname", "ismanaged", "uniquename" }),
            Criteria = new FilterExpression()
        };

        querySampleSolution.Criteria.AddCondition("uniquename".ToLower(), ConditionOperator.Like, "*" + solutionUniqueNameLike.ToLower() + "*");
        var solutions = service.RetrieveMultiple(querySampleSolution);
        //var filteredSolutions = solutions.Entities.Where(e => (e.Attributes.Contains("uniquename")) && (e.Attributes["uniquename"].ToString().ToLower() == "*" + solutionUniqueNameLike + "*"));
        if (solutions?.Entities?.Count > 0)
        {
            return solutions;
        }
        return null;
    }
```

But it is returning the 0 entities in the result.

I have also tried to search in the all solutions by using **LINQ** as added in the commented line of code above. But getting `NULL` in there.

EDIT 1: When I tried using `Contains` instead of `Like condition, it is throwing an error as below:

> System.ServiceModel.FaultException`1   HResult=0x80131501   Message=
>   Sql error: Generic SQL error. CRM ErrorCode: -2147204784 Sql
>   ErrorCode: -2146232060 Sql Number: 7601   Source=mscorlib
>
>   StackTrace:    at
>   System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.HandleReturnMessage(IMessage
>   reqMsg, IMessage retMsg)    at
>   System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.PrivateInvoke(MessageData&
>   msgData, Int32 type)    at
>   Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.IOrganizationService.RetrieveMultiple(QueryBase
>   query)    at
>   Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.Client.OrganizationServiceProxy.RetrieveMultipleCore(QueryBase
>   query)    at
>   Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.Client.OrganizationServiceProxy.RetrieveMultiple(QueryBase
>   query)    at
>   Microsoft.Xrm.Client.Services.OrganizationService.<>c__DisplayClass22.<RetrieveMultiple>b__21(IOrganizationService
>   s)    at
>   Microsoft.Xrm.Client.Services.OrganizationService.InnerOrganizationService.UsingService[TResult](Func`2
>   action)    at
>   Microsoft.Xrm.Client.Services.OrganizationService.RetrieveMultiple(QueryBase
>   query)    at TestProjectForCRM.Program.Main(String[] args) in
>   C:\Users\pratik.soni\source\repos\TestProjectForCRM\TestProjectForCRM\Program.cs:line
>   37

Not sure what I'm missing here.

Comment: if you are using a like condition you don't need to put the * in the value parameter, also that ToLower is useless as "uniquename" is already lowercase.

Comment: @Guido, I have tried without * and ToLower but result was unfortunately same.

Comment: can you try with Contains instead of Like?

Comment: @GuidoPreite: I have updated the output in my question. It is throwing an error as mentioned in question.

Comment: @GuidoPreite When I tried contains using FetchxmlBuilder it did indeed throw error as unkown operator.

Answer (score 0):

I want to add why you are seeing the below error:

> System.ServiceModel.FaultException1   HResult=0x80131501   Message=
>   Sql error: Generic SQL error. CRM ErrorCode: -2147204784 Sql
>   ErrorCode: -2146232060 **Sql Number: 7601**

The piece which will be useful is **Sql Number: 7601**, the [Database engine Events & Errors](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/errors-events/database-engine-events-and-errors?view=sql-server-2017) says `Cannot use a CONTAINS or FREETEXT predicate on %S_MSG '%.*ls' because it is not full-text indexed.`

[Refer my blog](https://arundynamix.blogspot.com/2019/06/troubleshooting-generic-sql-error-in.html) on how to crack this error message.